# Airflow with Okta integration

Tags: airflow, okta, okta-api, airflow-webserver

I'm attempting to integrate Airflow with Okta, however there is little documentation available online. I'm referring to a blog article, but I can't seem to get Okta to work.

Blog URL : https://tech.scribd.com/blog/2021/integrating-airflow-and-okta.html

If anyone has used Airflow with Okta, please share your experiences.

In addition, I followed all the steps outlined in [Airflow + Okta integration problem OAuth2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68683703/airflow-okta-integration-problem-oauth2-0).

I'm having the same problem with access prohibited.

Answer (score 1):

I had a bit of trouble getting this to work but in the end this is what I did:

Installed the following with PIP:

```
flask-appbuilder==3.4.5
sqlalchemy==1.3.18
authlib==1.0.1
```

in webserver_config.py

```
  from flask_appbuilder.security.manager import AUTH_OAUTH
  AUTH_TYPE = AUTH_OAUTH
  AUTH_ROLES_SYNC_AT_LOGIN = True
  AUTH_USER_REGISTRATION = True
  AUTH_USER_REGISTRATION_ROLE = "Admin"
  OAUTH_PROVIDERS = [
    {'name': 'okta', 'icon': 'fa-circle-o',
      'token_key': 'access_token',
      'remote_app': {
        'client_id': 'myclientid',
        'client_secret': 'myclientsecret',
        'api_base_url': 'https://myoktadomain.okta.com/oauth2/v1/',
        'client_kwargs': {
            'scope': 'openid profile email groups'
        },
        'access_token_url': 'https://myoktadomain.okta.com/oauth2/v1/token',
        'authorize_url': 'https://myoktadomain.okta.com/oauth2/v1/authorize',
        'jwks_uri': "https://myoktadomain.okta.com/oauth2/v1/keys"
      }
    }
  ]
```

Have the following settings in my Okta App:
[image]
[image]

Not shown in the screenshots I have these 2 settings as well:

Sign-in redirect URIs:

- https://myairflowurl.com/home
- https://myairflowurl.com/admin
- https://myairflowurl.com/oauth-authorized
- https://myairflowurl.com/login
- https://myairflowurl.com/oauth-authorized/okta

maybe we don't all of these???

**Initiate login URI:**
https://myairflowurl.com/login

As it stands, everyone who authenticates through Okta now gets Admin Access. I believe with some more work we can make use of roles / more granular permissions

Comment: Extending your response in terms of roles.
You can map roles between okta & airflow in a following way.
1. Add groups to airflow app on okta. Make sure they have some common naming convention like `airflow_admin`, `airflow_viewer`
2. Make sure you add a group claim filter them by prefix `airflow` in this case.
3. On airflow side you need to define a dictionary in webconfig.
```AUTH_ROLES_MAPPING = {"airflow_viewer": ["Viewer"],
    "airflow_admin": ["Admin"]}```
Source: https://support.okta.com/help/s/article/Okta-Groups-or-Attribute-Missing-from-Id-Token?language=en_US